# Выдает ошибку после отправки писем цепочкой (через @DataProvider), отправляется с помощью JavaMAIL Api

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sendmail, javamail

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] testInfo() throws IOException {
    return new Object[][] {

            {"mail1@yandex.ru","password","mail2@yandex.ru","password2"},
            {"mail3@yandex.ru","password3","mail4@yandex.ru","password4"},
            {"mail5@yandex.ru","password5","mail6@yandex.ru","password6"},

    };
}
@Test(dataProvider = "testInfo")
public void mailTest(String emailFrom,String passwordFrom,String emailTo,String passwordTo) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    Sender.send(emailFrom, passwordFrom, "mailSubject", "messsage", emailTo);
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

С первого на второй ящик отправляет, а потом выдает ошибку:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException:
>   553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user. ;
>
> nested exception is:    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException:
>   553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.